# Anchor Click and jQuery GET not working in FF and Safari but working in Chrome, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, safari

**QUESTION**
Very simple: In addition to the normal click functionality of an anchor tag `<a>` I want to fire off an ajax `GET` request if the anchor gets clicked (in my example attributed by `class` value `fire`).

**Important**: The destination of the anchor (href) as well as the destination of the `Ajax` call have the same domain in the target url.

Example jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fire').click(function() {
    $.get( "http://example.com/rest/fire/");
  });
});
```

Example HTML Code:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.html" class="fire">Click here</a>
```

In Chrome (v38) the asyncronous "fire and forget"-`GET` request is sent and then the browser shows the linked page. In Firefox (v32) and Safari (Yosemite), the asyncronous GET request does not get fired. Why?

I even tested it in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/29f9bryh/4/) (I only see the anchor GET request, not the Ajax GET request to `/rest/fire`)

**SOLUTION FOUND (UPDATED Oct 28th 2014)**
It does not work in Safari and Firefox because `$.get()` is using async mode per default (as I initially wanted it to be). However, if the target domain is the same as the URL of the `anchor` tag, Firefox and Safari just seem to ignore the `$.get()`. So in order to make it work, you have to make the ajax call **synchronously**!

Update jQuery Code (that works now also in Firefox and Chrome):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fire').click(function() {
    $.ajax({    
      url: "http://example.com/rest/fire/" ,
      async: false
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND (UPDATED Oct 28th 2014)**
It does not work in Safari and Firefox because `$.get()` is using async mode per default (as I initially wanted it to be). However, if the target domain is the same as the URL of the `anchor` tag, Firefox and Safari just seem to ignore the `$.get()`. So in order to make it work, you have to make the ajax call **synchronously**!

Update jQuery Code (that works now also in Firefox and Chrome):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fire').click(function() {
    $.ajax({    
      url: "http://example.com/rest/fire/" ,
      async: false // needed for Safari and Firefox
    });
  });
});
```

But I'm still convinced that this is a bug in Firefox and Safari, it should work with async mode as well. The root cause of the problem is most probably based on the implementation in the browsers how they establish connections to a single domain (multiplexed over one connection, multiple non-multiplexed connections?)... Maybe someone knows?

Answer (score -1):

You need to prevent the default action of the link. http://jsfiddle.net/d2o11rn9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fire').click(function(e) {
        $.get("/test");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Clayton, I will test it and give some feedback. Just to be sure, I want both to work: send ajax AND open new link...

Comment: Hi @Clayton, this does NOT work. It only fires the AJAX request. The normal anchor click does not work anymore. I need a solution where BOTH requests are executed.